# Difficulty getting pgfkeys to set my fontsizes as I want

Tags: pgfkeys, key-value

I apologize that this isn't particularly short.

I'm going through old code and refactoring.  In the process, I'm running into various *bugs* in how I've written things.  In this particular example, the font sizes are not getting properly initialized and I can figure out why.

My issue here is that I can't seem to get the `usefontsize/.initial` to take effect unless I explicitly make a call to the `fontsize` key.

```
%-@-(1)-
\begin{filecontents}{samplecode}
% first line of material I don't want to see
  \documentclass{article}
  \begin{document}
  document content here
  \end{document}
\end{filecontents}
%-@-(2)-
\begin{filecontents}{ncode}
\makeatletter
\def\ae@box@fbox{}
\def\ae@mboxheight{}
\def\ae@value@is@none{}
\def\code@cat{%
  \renewcommand{\FancyVerbFormatLine}[1]{##1}%
  \ae@ncode@set{fontsize/relsize={-0.75},
                examcodecolor,
                input/method={\VerbatimInput
                       [gobble=\ae@ncode@get{gobble},
                        firstline=\ae@ncode@get{firstline},
                        lastline=\ae@ncode@get{lastline},
                        firstnumber=\ae@ncode@get{firstnumber},
                        numbers=\ae@ncode@get{numbers},
                        numbersep=\ae@ncode@get{numbersep},
                        fontfamily=courier,
                        fontsize=\relsize{-0.75},
                       ]}}}
\pgfkeys
  {%
    /ae/ncode/.is family,
    /ae/ncode,
    %%:
    input/method/.initial,
    %%:
    examcode/.code       = {\code@cat},
    %%:
    gobble/.initial        = 2,
    width/.initial         = 3in,
    firstline/.initial     = 1,
    lastline/.initial      = 5000,
    firstnumber/.initial   = 1,
    rulecolor/.initial     = black,
    fillcolor/.initial     = red!20,
    numbers/.initial       = none,
    numbersep/.initial     = 1em,
    indent/.initial        = 0pt,
    %%:
    usefontsize/.initial     = \normalsize,
    fontsize/.style          = { usefontsize=\csname #1\endcsname},
    fontsize/relsize/.style  = { usefontsize=\relsize{#1}},
    %%:
    examcodecolor/.style   = { fillcolor=#1 },
    examcodecolor/.default = red!30,
    %%:
    mboxheight/.initial = \ae@mboxheight,
    height/.code = {\expandafter\ifx\csname ae@value@is@#1\endcsname\ae@value@is@none\else
                    \edef\ae@mboxheight{[#1]}\fi
                     },
    %%:
    /ae/ncode/.cd,
    fbox/.style = { select/box/style/#1/.get = \ae@box@fbox, }, 
    select/box/style/.cd,
      none/.initial,
      fbox/.initial      = \fbox,
      fcolorbox/.initial = \fcolorbox{\ae@ncode@get{rulecolor}}{\ae@ncode@get{fillcolor}},                   
  }
\def\ae@ncode@get#1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/ae/ncode/#1}}
\def\ae@ncode@set{\pgfqkeys{/ae/ncode}}
\newcommand{\nncode}[2][]{%
  \pgfqkeys{/ae/ncode}{usefontsize,#1}% <--- doesn't seem to matter whether `usefontsize` is here or not
  \edef\ae@begin@minipage{\noexpand\minipage[t]\ae@ncode@get{mboxheight}{\dimexpr\ae@ncode@get{width}-\ae@ncode@get{indent}}}%
  \ae@box@fbox{%
    \hspace*{\ae@ncode@get{indent}}%'
    \ae@begin@minipage
      \ae@ncode@get{usefontsize}% <--- doesn't seem to be taking effect in left version
      \ae@ncode@get{input/method}{#2}%'
    \endminipage}%' 
}
\makeatother
\end{filecontents}
%-@-(3)-
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\input{ncode}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}

Shouldn't the left and the right boxes look identical?

{\nncode[examcode,
        width={\dimexpr2.25in-2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep},
        fbox=fcolorbox,
        height=none,
        firstline=6,
        gobble=2,
        indent=0.5em,
        fontsize=normalsize,
       ]{samplecode}}%
%%'
{\nncode[examcode,
        width={\dimexpr2.25in-2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep},
        fbox=fcolorbox,
        height=none,
        firstline=6,
        gobble=2,
        indent=0.5em,
%        fontsize=normalsize,
       ]{samplecode}}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

I know there are parts of this code I could have written differently.  For example, it looks like I could have just written one key word `fontsize` to accept, not a bare word, but the actual command name for the font.  But keep in mind that I'm refactoring old code.  My old version of this code, when I was just learning to use *key-values*, didn't allow me to pass command names.  I now have hundreds of lines of code which now depend upon that old syntax.  So, I need a solution that recognizes the need for the `fontsize` key word to accept a bare word (instead of macro name) for its value.  Similarly with the wonky way I'm handling the keyword `height` since in my old code it's not always specified as a dimension.

**EDIT**

I should point out that there are other keys where I do similar *finagling*
with other initialized keys.  For example, `examcodecolor` resets the `fillcolor`, but seems to work fine whether or not `examcodecolor` was actually invoked.  A bit more off the beaten path is `height`, but if you redefine `\ae@mboxheight` as say:

```
\def\ae@mboxheight{[2in]}
```

without having to invoke `height` at all the correct parameter value is used.

Is there something special about `\normalsize` that I'm not considering?  Is it somehow being invoked at the time I'm defining `usefontsize/.initial`?

Comment: @cgnieder That shouldn't be the case at all.  `usefontsize` doesn't invoke the code involving `\csname...\endcsname`, and there's no where in my code where I write `fontsize=\normalsize`.

Comment: @cgnieder your suggestion should result in the string `normalsize` being printed in the final document.

Comment: Oh, you're right! I misread your code, sorry! Adding `usefontsize/.code = #1` additional to `usefontsize/.initial = normalsize` seems to work.

Comment: @cgnieder That works!  But why???  In all the other initialized key values, I can access and use their initialized value through `\ae@ncode@get`.  Why is that not the case with `usefontsize` and why then does writing `usefontsize/.code = #1,` produce the desired effect?

Comment: @cgnieder I guess I'd been thinking of something along those lines.  I'd been trying to write something like `usefontsize/.default = \normalsize`.  But that only gave me error messages.  if you could write up an answer explaining why `usefontsize/.code` works, why `usefontsize/.initial` is not sufficient, and why `usefontsize/.default` results in error messages, I'd be much obliged.

Comment: I would, but actually I'm not sure what's going on...

Comment: @cgnieder That's why I left the portion about how to set the `minipage`'s height in this MWE.  For example, if you define `\ae@mboxheight` as `[2in]`, with or without invoking `height`, the correct value is placed in the definition of the minipage environment.  This is quite stumper for me. In other words, I'm saying that the `height` scenario seems pretty similar to the `fontsize` scenario.  But, obviously something different is going on.

Comment: `usefontsize` is set to `\relsize{-0.75}` by `\code@cat` which you call implicitly by calling the `examcode` option. In the left example this is overwritten again, in the right it isn't.

Comment: @cgnieder Argh. How embarrassing that I couldn't find that one my own.  Thank you.  Then maybe this question should be closed?

Comment: @cgnieder An answer? Or a vote for closing.

Comment: @cgnieder Can you do something about this?

Comment: @clemens Yet another reminder for this with pretty please?

Comment: @percusse I'm unable to reproduce my proposed solution... :(

Comment: @cgnieder there is no proposed solution, this is just a side effect of `examcode`, so the value stored in `usefontsize` is once `\csname normalsize\endcsname` and once `\relsize{-0.75}`, and if your answer explains that then this finally has an answer :)